# Raspberry Pi GPIO and IRQ processing

Tags: go, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I am experimenting with the implementation of the manchester protocol for a 433 mhz transceiver. So I wrote a simple program that uses 2 pins - one for sending, another one for receiving the signal. The receiver part uses IRQ to intercept the edge change on the pin, and read its value to pass down to the manchester decoder. So far it looks good, in theory and tests, but in reality as soon as I start writing some data to the **transmitter** pin - the interrupt watcher on the **receiver** pin stops working. I use the same board for connecting the transmitter and the receiver parts.

I created some simple program to simply watch on the edge changes - and it intercepts the changes just fine, unless you use mem (wiringpi gpio) or sysfs to write a value to another pin. At this point the interrupts stop to happen.

Am I missing something?

Below is the original sample that uses GPIO 17 for reading and watching the edge change, and GPIO 21 for transmitting the signal.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jdevelop/go-manchester/manchester"
    "github.com/davecheney/gpio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func receive(bps int) {
    pin, err := gpio.OpenPin(17, gpio.ModeInput)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    frame := manchester.NewDataFrame()
    driver := manchester.NewManchesterDriver(int64(bps), 1000000)



    if err = pin.BeginWatch(gpio.EdgeBoth, func() {
        driver.ReadBit(manchester.Up, time.Now().UnixNano(), func(bool) {
            val := pin.Get()
            println(val)
            if frame.ReadBit(val) {
                println("DONE")
            }
        })
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer pin.EndWatch()
    defer pin.Close()

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println(frame)

}

func main() {

    text := os.Args[2]
    bps, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])

    driver := manchester.NewManchesterDriver(int64(bps), 100)
    frame := manchester.BuildDataFrame([]byte(text))

    pin, _ := gpio.OpenPin(21, gpio.ModeOutput)
    pin.Clear()

    defer pin.Close()

    logger := make(chan bool, 100)

    loggerF := func() {
        for {
            select {
            case lvl := <-logger:
                if lvl {
                    fmt.Print(1)
                } else {
                    fmt.Print(0)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    signal := func(level bool) {
        if level {
            pin.Set()
        } else {
            pin.Clear()
        }
    }

    go loggerF()
    go receive(bps)

    frame.WriteFrame(func(bit bool) {
        logger <- bit
        driver.WriteBit(bit, signal)
    })

    pin.Clear()

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Done")

}
```

Comment: How if you remove `fmt.Print` and other similar function (instead, write the data to a buffer etc.)? It may take some times and may affect the timing. Also add `default` to the select.

Comment: the timing is not the problem - the function in `BeginWatch` is never being invoked after the first write to the pin 21. I also tried the very same code w/o any write in the go code - started it and then `echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/value`. Before than the function on pin 17 is invoked couple of times per second (due to some noise), after - not invoked at all.

Comment: Then your code looks ok, except we don't know how you implement `ReadBit/WriteBit` and don't find a line/statement which prevents the application to exit before all the incoming data has been read. The above code will exit as soon as `frame.WriteFrame` being executed, and probably the data not yet arrived at receiving buffer. If this is not the problem, then you can try to attach interrupt to other pin (not GPIO17). Make sure the internal pull-up is activated, so the input pin is not floating. Sometimes, replacing the board may works.

Comment: the problem was in the logger - i have missed the `default` statement to intercept no status, and it went stuck at this point.